# Why can users under 10 reputation only use two hyperlinks in questions?

Tags: support, new-users, privileges

Today I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583951/python-alternatives-for-php-hash-functions#46583951) and a user asked a question. By the way, the OP needed to use four hyperlinks, but he said he can only use two hyperlinks. The OP said:

> P.S. I couldn't post links to last two links because of some goddamn
>   'have to have 10 reputation to post more than 2 links' stackoverflow
>   restriction.

(The PS is currently edited out, but can be seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46583951/2) revision.)

I couldn't find anything about this. Is this true and if it's true why should Stack Overflow have this restriction?

Comment: I guess for this exact reason. We want askers to include all relevant information **in the question** and not in links to offsite resources.

Comment: @ivarni I'm agree , but in this particular question OP want to link 4 function and reference them and it is not logical to paste all that links into question body.

Comment: So what happens once those links no longer work? If there's no way for them to ask a question without having it depend on offsite resources then it's probably not a question they should be asking anyway. Case in point; the question is off-topic.

Comment: @ivarni This is the problem with all links in all questions , this is not dependent on new user question

Comment: @Arman True, but a new user is less likely to know this since they apparently never read the help pages or take the tour when signing up.

Comment: *"Some User edit that question and removes the P.S. section ,I'm not sure this kind of editing is correct."* - Removing useless noise from a question is encouraged.

Comment: FYI, the limit was recently increased to 8 links.

Answer (score 11):

The limit is there to (try to) cut back on spam. 10 reputation is really easy to come by, so only completely new users are caught in these anti-spam measures, and they can still add the links as plain text if they want to.

Note that this limit is configurable per site. For example, [on Skeptics the limit is 50 links](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2083).

---

Since this answer was posted, [the limit has been increased from 2 to 8 links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302390/remove-the-2-link-limit-for-new-users-everywhere/302451#302451).

Comment: If they can still add links as a plain text, it means this restriction is not very useful, and why hyperlink to other sites is _spam_?

Comment: @Arman There are fewer problems associated with spam as tex then spam as links in my opinion.